# Fatal error when trying to send an email in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm getting the following Fatal error when trying to send an email in ZF2:
**Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException' not found in /var/www/zend/ZendFramework-minimal-2.0.6/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php on line 262**

The code triggering this is:

```
$email = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
$email->setBody('This is a test body.');
$email->setFrom('sender@example.com', 'Sender Name');
$email->addTo('recipient@example.com', 'Recipient Name');
$email->setSubject('Test Subject');

$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Mail\Transport')->send( $email );

die("I am here");
```

Where `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Mail\Transport')` returns an instance of Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.

However the issue seems to be quite odd because:

- The email is actually always sent despite the error.
- The error doesn't seem to be trigged until after the script. In the example above, the script is outputting "I am here" and then Fatal error afterwards.
- This *seems* to be linked to where the above code block appears. For example, the error is triggered when the block appears in some Controllers, but not others, despite the only difference between the controllers being their name.

If anyone could give me a clue as to why this is happening I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Have you checked whether there is a file "Zend/Mail/Protocol/Exception/RuntimeException.php"?

Comment: @Niko - Yes, the Zend/Mail/Protocol/Exception/RuntimeException.php file is there.

Comment: Have you setup autoloading properly?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I'm using the Skeleton Application; so everything else seems to be working perfectly. It's just this one action that's returning an error.